# How do I parse YAML into a hash/object?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a YAML file with a few entries that look like this:

```
001:
  :title: Some title
  :description: Some body text maybe
002:
  :title: Some title
  :description: Some body text maybe
```

I'm using the following Ruby method to parse that YAML file into a set of objects I can iterate over:

```
def parse_yaml(file)
  YAML::load(File.open(File.join(settings.yaml_folder, file)))
end

def use_yaml
  @items = parse_yaml('items.yml')
  @items.each do |item|
    x = item[1][:title]
    etc...
  end
end
```

Now, that method works, but I find it queer that I need to use `item[1][:title]` to access the attributes of the object I'm iterating over.  How can I build my YAML file or my parsing code to allow me to use the more standard `item[:title]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a Hash. The `parse_yaml` output is:

```
{ 1=>
      { :title=>"Some title",
        :description=>"Some body text maybe"},
  2=> { :title=>"Some title",
        :description=>"Some body text maybe" }
}
```

You may to use the [`each_value`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each_value) method like this:

```
#...
@items = parse_yaml('items.yml')
@items.each_value do |item|
    x = item[:title]
    # ... etc
end
```

Recomend: [YAML for Ruby](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html)

Answer (score 7):

The underlying issue is that your YAML file is storing your data as a hash, and trying to access it like an array.

To convert your data into array format:

```
---
- :title: Some title
  :description: Some body text maybe
- :title: Some title
  :description: Some body text maybe
```

Also interesting to note, the reason you had to use `item[1][:title]` to reference your items is that the keys `001` and `002` are converted to integers by YAML.load.

You can confirm this in irb:

```
irb(main):015:0> YAML.load(File.open("./test.yml"))
=> {1=>{:title=>"Some title", :description=>"Some body text maybe"}, 2=>{:title=>"Some title", :description=>"Some body text maybe"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your YAML is the serialisation of a hash so you could do:

```
@items.each do |key, item|
  #do something with item[:title]
end
```

Or change your YAML to look like:

```
- :title: blah
  :description: description
- :title: second title
  :description: second description
```

Which will result in `YAML.load` returning an array.